# "Hold off something" or "hold off on something" in the sense of delaying something?

Tags: prepositions

Would you please tell me if I need to include *on* after *hold off* in the sense of delaying something in the sentence below?

> Can we hold off (**on**) the pick for two hours?

Is it natural to include *on* there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving out *on* would change the meaning, since "hold off" and "hold off on" are two different phrases:

- *[hold off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20off)*, when used transitively, means to resist something's advances or attacks ("The villagers *held off* the Vikings for two hours"). Confusingly, if you use it *intransitively*—having no object—then it means something similar to "hold off on"; it simply means to wait: "They want a decision, but I'll hold off for two hours."
- *[hold off on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20off%20on)* always needs an object, but has that same meaning of "to wait [to do something]": "Can we hold off on the pick for two hours?"